# Conditionally creating vertex in Titan

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, titan

I have a situation where I need to check if a vertex with three satisfying properties property1='a',property2='b',property3='c' already exists in a graph and if it does not exist, I need to create it. Basically there should be a unique vertex in the graph with the combination of these three properties. I have tried out this snippet of gremlin code to check based on one property 'id'

```
getOrCreate = { id ->
  def p = g.V('userId', id)
  if (p.hasNext()) ? p.next() : g.addVertex([userId:id])
```

Not very clear about the best way to modify this to achieve what i need with gremlin since I'm a beginner. All I can think of is nesting more if's and else's in the last statement. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches.  One way would be to extend your traversal a bit:

```
getOrCreate = { one, two, three ->
  def p = g.V('prop1', one).has('prop2',two).has('prop3',three)
  p.hasNext() ? p.next() : g.addVertex([prop1:one,prop2:two,prop3:three])
```

In the above code, `prop1` represents an indexed property, then you just filter on the rest.  That `prop` should be the most selective property in that it should filter out the most results.

If for some reason `prop` is not selective enough then this solution might not be fast enough.  In other words, if you have 1 billion vertices and `g.V('prop1', one)` returns 100000 then you will be in-memory filtering those, which will be kinda slow.  If this is your case, I would consider creating a "poor-man's" composite index, by adding a fourth property to index on that combines all three properties into one.  Then just do your lookups on that.

Comment: Can you confirm that this would work for multiple concurrent clients? E.g. If you were calling this via 2 gremlin clients at the same time, what would happen? There are scenarios that spring to mind that unless this is an atomic operation will result in the creation of 2 vertices with the same properties. (Unique indexes could be used but I think that's avoiding the conditional create request).

Comment: From a Titan perspective, assuming you are using one of the eventually consistent backends like Cassandra, you would need to have some form [locking](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/eventual-consistency.html) in place to help prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

```
getOrCreate = { p1, p2, p3 ->
  def p = g.V().has('property1', p1).has('property2', p2).has('property3', p3)
  p.hasNext() ? p.next() : g.addVertex(['property1':p1,'property2':p2,'property3':p3])
}
```

Cheers,
Daniel